# SO avatar shown in SourceTree?

Tags: discussion, gravatar

I just noticed SourceTree installed on my Mac shows exactly the same avatar used in my SO account. This is an auto-generated avatar, I've not changed it in any way.

How did SourceTree get hold of the flair used in SO?

- Is this just a coincidence?
- Does SourceTree somehow access the SO account?
- Or is the avatar generated using an algorithm which takes my name or email as an input (i.e given the same input, does it generate the same flair every time?)

This is not an issue for me, but I'm just curious to know.

Comment: StackExchange uses Gravatar. SourceTree uses Github. Github uses Gravatar. Gravatar contains email and profile picture. StackExchange creates flair based on email. I can see how they relate but you should probably ask Atlassian.

Comment: I think you have your terms mixed up. Your 'flair' is the image Stack Overflow generates with your avatar image and your score and badges. Yours is http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/434319.png. Are you talking about just your *avatar image* instead? The geometric pattern generated by Gravatar based on your email address?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SourceTree does not access your Stack Overflow account, no.

I think you are talking about your avatar image:

[image]

The URL for this image is `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c8b36f3a5e5efced29c9ebdf9e1a4276?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG`; it contains a hash of your email address, and some parameters to control size, usage and rating (you can use different avatars for different contexts).

This image is generated by Gravatar.com based on your email address. Stack Overflow is not the only site that uses this service. GitHub uses it too, for example. If you are using the same email address on Stack Overflow and on other services, then SourceTree is being given the same image by that service.

Note that your *flair* is something different; that is the image generated by Stack Overflow with your reputation and badges; this *contains* your avatar but is unique to Stack Overflow. Yours looks like:

[image]

although you can pick from a few themes, and there is a Stack Exchange network-wide variant that shows your total reputation across the network (for accounts with 200 points or more).